# Displaying a navigation menu horizontal chrome issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, cross-browser

I'm displaying a menu horizontally using a [previous question that was answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112425/how-can-i-make-a-navigation-menu-fit-its-container-horizontally), but it does not seem to be working in Google Chrome.

It works fine in Firefox, IE, Safari looks different but doesn't drop the last menu item off.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nilpo/GGQ4V/3/

As mentioned in the previous question that was answered, I need to menu items to fit the size of the container that it is in. However, the solution doesn't work on Google Chrome and I don't know why.

Comment: Odd - it appears fine to me in Chrome 21.0.1180.89 / Mac 10.8. Everything seems to be fitting as it should. Have you experimented with tweaking padding by like a pixel to see if it will fit then for you? As a generality: Menus like this, that are designed to fill a horizontal space **exactly**, in general, are poor design decisions on the web. They're too inflexible, and prone to breaking.

Comment: I agree @chipcullen. I did not design the site, and was not part of the design process for the menu - I would of advised against it. So, I have Chrome Version 22.0.1229.79 and Mac 10.7.5... I guess it could be a on page load issue with the script?

Comment: I suppose it could. That'd be the only reason why two relatively close releases of Chrome would behave differently. I'd just see if a slightly narrower width, or reduced border thickness, would do the trick first. That would at least isolate the rendering issue.

Comment: adjusting the border width is actually causing it to look worse. So your saying that it looks fine on your setup?

Comment: Well, I was checking Chrome > About Chrome, which was saying I was up to date. Then I noticed the the update indicator under my settings, so I now just updated to 22. And now, unfortunately, the menu is hosed. So, in Chrome 21, it was fine, in 22 it's not. Very, very odd.

Comment: Well thanks for that information, that's great - but also really annoying.

Comment: Is your container always always always going to be 960? If so, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't give display: table;

```
.menu-main-menu-container ul {
----------------------
}
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sselvamani22/GGQ4V/18/)

Answer (score 0):

[I just tried this on the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GGQ4V/17/), and got it to work in Chrome 22:

```
.menu a {
    padding:         5px 14px 5px 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    position:        relative;
    font: 15px 'DroidSerifBold', Arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

And I disabled the Javascript altogether. If your container is a fixed width, and the menu items aren't changing, you shouldn't need the JS.